# Download file using springboot and angular

Tags: angular, spring

Im using angular and spring and i am trying to download file.

I can download file using only spring('http://localhost:8080/download) but i dont know how to connect it with angular.
for spring i'am using ResponseEntitiy
here is the code

```
 @GetMapping(value ="/download")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadFile() throws IOException, PropertyException, JAXBException
    {
        bookListService.convertBookListToXml();
        return bookListService.downloadXml();
        
    };
```

and service

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadXml() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filename = "booksExport.xml";
    File file = new File(filename);
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition",
            String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/txt")).body(resource);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

I tried many options to connect response with angular but none is working.
is ResponseEntity even good return?

angular is currently
html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="downloadFile2()">download File</button>
```

component.ts

```
  downloadFile2() {
    this.fileDownloadService.downloadFile3();
  }
```

and service

```
  downloadFile3(): any {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/download');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ResponseEntity use the type InputStreamResource, add the info at the header and pass the file in the body, like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> viewCheckExcel() throws JRException, IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = service.generateFile();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=customers.xlsx");
 return ResponseEntity
              .ok()
              .headers(headers)
              .body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
```

This is for a File Excel but the structure is the same.

For convert the file in ByteArrayInputStream in the service you can do like this:

```
File file = new File(wfc.getPathExcel()+"/customer.xlsx");
return new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

NB: In the method of the FrontEnd specify the type of file that recive.